# Counting through all binary numbers with equal 1's and 0's

Tags: partitioning, combinations

I'm implementing a binary representation of an equal-side bi-partitioning algorithm and I'm wondering what the best way to iterate through all combinations of N bits that have equal (N/2) 1's and 0's.  I'm trying to find the quickest way, not the easiest to code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `(N choose N/2)`; you're choosing which bits are 0s, the rest are 1s.

If you have 10 bits, and you want 5 zeroes and 5 ones, there are [`(10 choose 5) = 252`](http://www.google.co.id/search?q=10+choose+5) possibilities.

---

#### See also:

- [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

---

As has been pointed out, this number is the binomial coefficient `(n k)`. When `k` is `n/2` is when this coefficient is the largest; I'm sure you're aware that there are numerous possibilities, which is why you wanted the fastest algorithm to generate them.

Instead of micro-optimizing this generator to make it the fastest possible, I'd first exhaust all other options: are you sure you can't do any better than trying all possibilities? This brute force solution does not scale.

Try to find a better algorithm if at all possible.

Comment: Interesting.  Is that choose function what they call a binomial coeffecient?  i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: Yes, I believe "n choose k" is how you casually say it in English, and it's also how Google calculator does it (just type in "`10 choose 5`"). It is the binomial coefficient, which of course appears in a lot of places (e.g. Pascal's triangle, etc).

Comment: Just be aware that on some architecture (e.g. Intel) recursive implementations can sometimes be faster (!) than their iterative equivalents.  Implement both and measure.